# Hide a textfield based on value inside an hidden field which was filled automatically by a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a strange problem over here. I basically have a form which has a field for entering card number.Depending on the card number,a java script automatically detects the card type (maestro,or visa or whatever ).suppose if the card number detected by the javascript is 'maestro' , it will add this value to the hidden field in the form.

Now what I want is another javascript which detects the value in the hidden field (its `id="ccType"` and should hide a text field with `id="cvv"`

```
$('#ccType').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'maestro')
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').hide(); 
    else
        $('#cvv').closest('.name').show();
});
```

this javascript which I tried really works,if the hidden field (`id='ccType'` is not hidden)and I manually enter the value 'maestro' to it,it is hiding the cvv field.But instead of manually entering the ccType,as I told earlier I have a javascript which automatically detects the card type and fills the `id=ccType` field.But then the above code doesnt work.It works only if I manually add a value to the ccType field,and when the field loose focus,the cvv is hidden,Other wise not !

I cant find an other way around to hide cvv when the ccType field is automatically filled by the autodetetcting/autofilling javascript.

I have fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/y8UKN/5/ .I have given both the scripts,the one which auto fills and the one for hiding the cvv( its not working :D )

For simplicity,i have removed the 'hidden' attribute of the ccType field so that you can see the value inside it.try filling the card number with a number starting with "6" it will detect maestro and the field will be filled and this value 'maestro' should hide the ccv.

I know this can be a confusing question.But i have tried my maximum to provide a clear picture and made a working fiddle as well.Waiting for a response soon.

Thanks

Comment: i can't see any scripts in your fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i understand from your question is that when you make your Field hidden it does not triggers change event.

try triggering your change event manually like this

```
$( "#ccType" ).trigger( "change" );
```

when you set your hidden field value, after that add this code line

**EDIT**

add above line here

```
if($(".cards li:not('.off')").length == 1){
       $('#ccType').val($(".cards li:not('.off')").attr('class'));
       $( "#ccType" ).trigger( "change" );
}
```

Comment: can you help me out with my fiddle?

Comment: there is NO JS added in you fiddle

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/y8UKN/6/ i do not know your business logic test your logic on it, is it working?

Comment: Have you made any changes?

Comment: mark as correct if it works for you so others should not put effort on it

Comment: ya ill.but seems this working really well in the fiddle.I tried copying out the script in the server and when i try,it doesnt work..i dont knw why.

Comment: make sure your JS files included

Comment: Yes I have included both the js files.I have added the scripts in the header as well as body.i tried both.but it doesnt work.Its detecting the card and filling it in the field,but not hdiding the cvv.this is the lnik   http://fethr.com/paymentcard/card/cardpayment.html

Comment: what could be the prob?

Comment: Hi.I have added the scripts inside body.Now its working :).Thank you so much for you help